# I am getting MethodNotAllowedHttpException when uploading large excel sheet records to my database

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to import data from excel file to my database , the problem is when i upload too many records i get this error message

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219

Here is my code:

**route.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'panel', 'middleware' => 'adminMiddleware'], function () {
    Route::get('/index', 'admin\AdminController@index');
    Route::post('/uploadUsersExcel', 'admin\AdminController@uploadUsersExcel');
    Route::post('/downloadUsersExcel', 'admin\AdminController@downloadUsersExcel');

});
```

**AdminController.php**

```
  public function uploadUsersExcel(Request $request)
    {


        if ($request->file('file')) {
            $name = 'uploads/csv/' . $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
            $request->file('file')->move('uploads/csv/', $name);
            DB::table('users')->whereNotIn('id', [1])->delete();

            Excel::filter('chunk')->load($name)->chunk(250, function($reader)

            {

                $data = $reader->toArray();

                foreach ($data as $value) {
                    $user = new user();
                    $user->password = bcrypt($value['password']);
                    $user->save();
               }
            }

            );

        }

    }
```

**users.blade.php**

```
            {!! Form::open(['files'=>true,'method'=>'post','url'=>'panel/uploadUsersExcel']) !!}
                        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="file"/>
                        <button type="submit"  class="bigger-icon btn btn-block  btn-success">


upload
                        </button>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: what is your form ?

Comment: i added it to the question.

Comment: Are you sure that when you get this `MethodNotAllowedException` you are at the right URL? Check if when you get this error you are at `myapp.dev/panel/uploadUsersExcel` and not at `myapp.dev/something/panel/uploadUsersExcel` ?

Comment: i checked and i found the URL mywebsite/panel/uploadUsersExcel,the controller works without any errors when the number of records in the excel file are small.

Comment: @wahdan This might be a longshot but try adding this at the top of start of the uploadUsersExcel method `ini_set('memory_limit','256M')` . If this fixes your issue then please consider using laravel queue system to handle large file uploads in the background. hard setting memory limit should be avoided or hastily replaced with background jobs

Comment: increasing memory_limit to 512M didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

Add the `enctype` to your form tag.

```
 {!! Form::open(['files'=>true,'method'=>'post','url'=>'panel/uploadUsersExcel', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
```

Then increase your **post_max_size**, **upload_max_filesize** in your `php.ini` if you're uploading files larger than specified in `php.ini`

Comment: The `'files'=>true` should be sufficient :/

Comment: ok i added enctype , and here is my php.ini info
post_max_size  128MB
max_execution_time 5000
max_file_uploads 20
upload_max_filesize 1G

unfortunately i got the same error.

Comment: @wahdan ```upload_max_filesize```

Comment: @wahdan answer updated. ```post_max_size``` for POST request in general, ```upload_max_filesize``` applies for files. So simply increase both.

Comment: @wahdan can to verify if the values actually changed? use ```phpinfo();``` and look there. (Make sure to restart your service after making any changes)

Comment: ok i used phpinfo() and here are the results :
post_max_size           128M
upload_max_filesize   1G
max_execution_time   5000

Comment: How much the file size?

Comment: the file size is only 235 KB

Comment: I had same problem i increased my post size stuff, and it worked for me. but seems you have no problem with laravel if you say it works for small files

Comment: Can you update your question and show your ```adminMiddleware```